# How do you also pass label tag values in a form in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that has label values that I would like to pass to my controller on the submit post.  Right now the params from the post only includes values from input and radio_button tags.  How do I also include the values in the label tags I have in my form?

This is a simplified view of how my code looks like:

```
  = form_for :user, :url => create_user_path do  |f|
    = f.label :name, "Name: #{@widgit.name}"
    = f.submit
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use hidden fields; labels are just text so not sent.